# Origin of Vikram-Beetal stories?

Tags: belief, culture, story

The *Vikram-Betaal* stories are derived from the Vetālapañcaviṃśati (वेतालपञ्चविंशति) or famously called, 
  [Baital Pachisi](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baital_Pachisi) ("Twenty-five (tales) of Baital").

Do these stories find any kind of reference or allusion to, in any form whatsoever, in the scriptures? Or should they be only considered as local folkloric tales ( *दंत कथायें* ) and cultural stories, in line with the stories of *Singhasan Battisi*?

Also, is *Beetal* some kind of or a class of some supernatural entity or creatures within the *Hindu* pantheon?

Comment: Last one, yes beetal is a kind of demon. In Hinduism

Comment: I guess its vetal or beetal. Whatever, he is a Munja (a class of ghost, like pishach etc) and I guess king of all ghosts.